# Scala-Why can't I use MD5 to encrypt a file?

Tags: scala, md5

I am trying to encrypt a file with MD5.Listing below are my codes.

```
import java.security.MessageDigest
import scala.io.Source
import java.io.PrintWriter
import java.io.File

    object MD5 {
      def md5(file: String)= {
        val text=Source.fromFile(file)
        val s=text.mkString
        val hash = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5").digest(s.getBytes)
        hash.map("%02x".format(_)).mkString
        }

     def main(args:Array[String])={
        val cipher=md5("InputFile")
        val pw = new PrintWriter(new File("OutputFile"))
        pw.write(cipher)
        pw.close
      }}
```

No matter how big my InputFile is,the OutputFile always seems to be the same size(about 10 bytes).Where is the problem? Can someone help me to figure it out?

Comment: MD5 is not an encryption algorithm, but a hash algorithm...

Comment: @CyrilleCorpet that is to say,we cannot encrypt a file with MD5?

Comment: You can use MD5 to get a hash code, but not to get an encrypted version of the file that you can later decrypt. So, what do you *actually* want to do - calculate an MD5 hash of the file, or encrypt the file so that you can later decrypt it? If you want to encrypt the file, you need something else than MD5.

Comment: MD5 is a 128 Bit hash function. The output file size should be 16 Bytes, not 10.

Comment: Your code works as written. I tried giving it a bad file name to see if that was causing the problem, but on my system it throws an exception as expected. FWIW the output size should be 32 since output is formatted as 2-digit hex.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By "ecnryption" people usually mean such a transformation of data that someone with proper "secret data" can reverse that transformation.

["Hash function"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function) on the other hand is by definition non-uniquely reverisble transformation that transforms arbitratry data to a fixed-sized "hash". [MD5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5) is an old [cryptographic hash function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function) which means that this is a "hash function" with additional crypto-related properties (such as it is hard to find a collision). Sidenote: MD5 is old enough to not be considered crypto-strong anymore. Typical current usages of MD5 is to verify data integrity.

So yes, MD5 is a wrong thing to use for encryption. If you want encryption, take a look at [AES ciphers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard)